# Is cross-sectional area over length classified separately from length?

Tags: electricity, units, dimensional-analysis, length

The ratio of cross-sectional area to length (or its reciprocal) appears in several formulas, including those for electrical resistance and capacitance in terms of the resistivity and permittivity. However, I've never heard a term or a separate name for this.

The [Wikipedia article on length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length) claims:

> In the International System of Quantities, length is any quantity with dimension distance.

The ratio described has dimension distance; yet, intuitively, it is very different from length. Is it considered differently from length, and if so, is there a term for it?

Comment: Something with constant area/length is a paraboloid. In this specific case "focal length" would be one such term. In this case, yes it is an actual length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation for capacitance is $C=\kappa \epsilon_0 A / d$ and the equation for electrical resistance is $R=\rho L / A$.  While it is true that an isolated fraction of $A/d$ dimensionally reduces to a length and an isolated fraction of $L/A$ dimensionally reduces to the reciprocal of length, that is not the point of the listed equations.  Any physics equation normally contains the minimum number of independent variables that describes the different things that interact to produce the physical interaction and result that is being observed.

For electrical resistance, a wire's resistance will directly increase with increasing length, and its resistance will directly decrease with increasing cross-sectional area.  These two variables need not be changed separately, as you can easily specify a wire that is twice as long, with twice the cross-sectional area, if you want to leave the resistance unaffected.  Such a decision may be necessary in the real world if you find that an original estimated length is short by a factor of 1.5 and wires are only sold in standard lengths.  Naturally, if the resistance equation was dimensionally reduced to $R=\rho/L$, the respecification problem would be totally obscured, and everyone would conclude that a doubling of length automatically resulted in a halving of resistance, which is clearly incorrect.  The same type of argument can be given for the capacitance equation.

Thus, physics equations are written in a way that allows people to $read$ the equation such that they can determine the relationship between ALL of the important variables involved in the relevant situation.  Any dimensional over-simplification of such equations destroys the ability to properly read such an equation, and necessarily destroys most of the important information that such an equation was meant to convey.

Comment: So, they are fundamentally different quantities despite having the same dimension. Is there any term for this ratio of area to length (in three separate dimensions)? It appears to pop up in other equations, like the equation for stiffness under Hooke's law.

Comment: @hyperum, please re-read my response.  Physics is NOT math.  Physics equations have a particular form for a good reason, which transcends math or dimensional simplification.  And no, the ratio of area to length doesn't have a special name, because the equations that contain this ratio are telling you MUCH MORE than something about this ratio.

Comment: I’m not convinced that asking for this ratio is asking for “”dimensional simplification””. If so, then torque is meaningless because it’s in the same units as energy, and so on and so forth for the other quantities of rotational kinematics and dimensionless quantities. I’ll just take your answer that it doesn’t exist.

Comment: Torque, expressed in Newton-meters, is NOT the same as work, which can also be expressed in Newton-meters, because work requires a displacement while torque does not require a displacement.  In the past, I've told my physics students to report torque in Newton-meters and work in Joules, which makes sense, since work and energy are equivalent.  I encourage you to work more physics problems and think about physics in terms of the underlying concepts rather than the math that is involved.

Comment: I know it’s not the same, it’s just that I’m trying to express that quantities don’t have to be meaningless if they share a dimension, just as you imply with a/l and length. If people are not confused with torque as separate from energy, they would not be confused with a/l as separate from length unlike what you say in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The quantity is referred to as the "Shape Factor".  In idealized two dimensional cases it is unitless, which indicates that the shape factor is independent of size (akin to an aspect ratio).  In three dimensions it has units of meters and is size dependent.